# scalar variable error

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

if you please heap me out i have an error

error:

Must declare the scalar variable "@Criteria".

since i don't have a lot of experience i can not find the problem thanks

code:

```
public static void CreateReveiw(string paperId, string Criteria_Id, string Grate)
{



    var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);




    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = sqlCon;
    cmd.CommandText = "select Review_paper_ID from ReviewPaper where Paper_ID= @PaperId";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PaperId", paperId);
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    string Review_paper_ID = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    cmd.Connection.Close();
    cmd.Dispose();





    string query2 = @"insert into ReviewPaperCriteria(Review_paper_ID,Criteria_ID,Grate) 
                     values(@Review_paper_ID,@Criteria,@Grate);select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as RPID";

    cmd = new SqlCommand(query2, sqlCon);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Review_paper_ID", Review_paper_ID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Criteria_ID", Criteria_Id);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Grate", Grate);

    string ReviewPaperId;

    try
    {
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        ReviewPaperId = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        cmd.Connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ee) { throw ee; }
    finally { cmd.Dispose(); }



    }
```

Comment: **Never** write `catch (Exception ee) { throw ee; }`.  It destroys the stack trace.

Comment: @SLaks will `catch (Exception ee) { throw; }` maintain stack trace?

Comment: @Bala: Yes.  That's fine, but useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring the variable `@Criteria` but attempting to set its value using `@Criteria_ID`.

Change

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Criteria_ID", Criteria_Id);
```

To

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Criteria", Criteria_Id);
```

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Criteria_ID", Criteria_Id);
```

to

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Criteria", Criteria_Id);
```

or change the query string (query2) to match the parameter name (@Criteria_ID) that's used.

Answer (score 3):

Your parameter is `@Criteria_ID` but you reference `@Criteria` in the SQL. You need to change it in one of the locations to be consistent.

```
string query2 = @"insert into ReviewPaperCriteria(Review_paper_ID,Criteria_ID,Grate) 
                 values(@Review_paper_ID,@Criteria,@Grate);select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as RPID";
                                         ^^^^^^^^^    
...

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Criteria_ID", Criteria_Id);
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```